# Coloring $\mathbb R^3$ with 3 colors always gives us a color with all distances.

Tags: coloring

I'm having some issues reasoning through a particular problem. Consider a
problem where I color all points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the colors red, green,
blue. I want to show that every positive real represents the distance between
two points of one of these colors (one color attains all distances). I have a
feeling that this is to some extent an "assume for sake of contradiction"
kind of proof. Let us say that there is no color that attains all distances,
i.e. red does not attain $d_{r},$ blue does not attain $d_{b},$ and green does
not attain $d_{g}.$ $d_{r}$ represents the distance between blue or green
points, $d_{b}$ represents the distance between red or green points, and
$d_{g}$ represents the distance between red or blue points. However, once I
reach this point, I am running out of ideas of where to move with this proof.
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just making sure you stated the problem correctly. Do you want to show that there is some color such that every real is the distance between two points of that color, or that every real is the distance between two points of the same color (which could vary depending on the real)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose red, blue, green don't attain $d_r$, $d_b$, $d_g$ respectively, with $d_r \ge d_b \ge d_g$.  I'll leave it to you to handle the case where there is no red point.  Otherwise, take a red point $p_r$.  Then the sphere $S$ of radius $d_r$ centred there contains only blue and green.  If it's all green,
green  would attain $d_g$ for any two points at distance $d_g$ on $S$, so there is at least one blue point $p_b$ on $S$.  The intersection of $S$ with the sphere of radius $d_b$ centred at $p_b$ is an all-green circle of radius $ y > d_b/2 \ge d_g/2$ so this circle contains
two points at distance $d_g$, contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a tetrahedron of side length $x\in\mathbb{R}$. By pigeonhole principle at least two vertices are the same color. Hence the distance $x$ is represented by the distance between two points of the color.

Comment: OP wants to prove there is a color that covers all distances, not one color for each individual distance.